# How to simplify this method (splitting unquoted, unbracketed, unescaped commas)?

Tags: c#, parsing

Curious if this can be simplified...

```
internal static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, char sep = ',')
{
    int lastIndex = 0;
    bool quoted = false;
    bool escaped = false;
    bool bracketed = false;
    char lastQuote = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] == '[')
        {
            if (!quoted && !escaped)
                bracketed = true;
            escaped = false;
        }
        else if (str[i] == ']')
        {
            if (!quoted && !escaped)
                bracketed = false;
            escaped = false;
        }
        else if (str[i] == '\\')
        {
            escaped = !escaped;
        }
        else if (str[i] == '"' || str[i] == '\'')
        {
            if (!escaped)
            {
                if (quoted)
                {
                    if (lastQuote == str[i])
                        quoted = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    quoted = true;
                    lastQuote = str[i];
                }
            }
            escaped = false;
        }
        else if (str[i] == sep)
        {
            if (!quoted && !escaped && !bracketed)
            {
                yield return str.Substring(lastIndex, i - lastIndex);
                lastIndex = i + 1;
            }
            escaped = false;
        }
        else
        {
            escaped = false;
        }
    }

    yield return str.Substring(lastIndex);
}
```

Wrote this method to split on commas that aren't inside `[]`, are not quoted, and are not escaped. Is this inherently a tricky problem, or did I take a dumb approach?

Input:

```
foreach(var sel in SharpQuery.SplitCommas("\"comma, in quotes\", comma[in,brackets], comma[in \"quotes, and brackets\"], \"woah, 'nelly,' \\\"now you,re [talking, crazy\\\"\"")) {
    Console.WriteLine(sel);
}
```

Expected output:

```
"comma, in quotes"
 comma[in,brackets]
 comma[in "quotes, and brackets"]
 "woah, 'nelly,' \"now you,re [talking, crazy\""
```

Comment: have you thought about regex??

Comment: The code you have produced while perhaps not the most concise or elegant is *maintainable* - which (in my opinion) is one of the most important thing for code to be. Is this code causing any issues? If not I'd leave it alone.

Comment: @jimplode: Yes, and I believe that would be an awful approach, if it's even doable. @ChrisF: Seems to work in the tests I've ran. I'm not too worried about optimizing it, just wondering if it could be simplified further... it suffers from a bit of code redundancy and stuff.

Comment: @Mark - in that case follow the DRY principle and factor out the repeated code into new methods.

Comment: @Mark: why would that be an awful approach? Surely you need to run look ahead matching? also, looking at your example, the brackets and quotes seem random... I am confused by what you are trying to read? is this some document you have to read, or just some random task you wish to complete?

Comment: @jimplode: Because matching quotes in regexes is hard, matching brackets in regexes is hard, matching unescaped things in regexes is tricky, but doing them all in one regex? You tell me how to write that. The example is random, yes... a real example would look like this `tag.class1.class2#id[attr1=val1][attr2=\"complex,val\"][attr3]:pseudo, selector2`.

Comment: @Mark: So because something is not easy it is an awful approach? What is it you are trying to capture from that string? who said you had to do it in one regex? it might make more sense to do it in several.

Comment: @jimplode: Because it's not easy to read, write, and maintain? Yes, that makes it a bad approach. I don't see how you can do this in several regexes either.. unless maybe you want to regex-replace out the irrelevant parts, and then do a simple string split on the remaining bit, but... I don't see how that's any better.

Comment: jimplode: I'd *love* to see a regex that performs this task! By all means, post one and I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit of an awkward choice to keep your automaton state. I would use a single variable or a stack in this case. So your current state is always `stateStack.Peek()`. Easy to read. Easy to handle nested states.

edit: heres a quick sample. I'm sure you can expand it to add error handling and specifics of your rules.

```
    enum ParserState
    {
        Text,
        Bracketed,
        Quoted,
        EscapChar,
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, char sep)
    {
        int lastIdx = 0;
        char c;
        ParserState s;
        Stack<ParserState> state = new Stack<ParserState>();
        state.Push(ParserState.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            c = str[i];
            s = state.Peek();

            if (s == ParserState.EscapChar
                || (s == ParserState.Bracketed && c == ']')
                || (s == ParserState.Quoted && c == '"'))
            {
                state.Pop();
            }
            else if (c == '[')
                state.Push(ParserState.Bracketed);
            else if (c == '"')
                state.Push(ParserState.Quoted);
            else if (c == '\\')
                state.Push(ParserState.EscapChar);
            else if (s == ParserState.Text && c == sep)
            {
                yield return str.Substring(lastIdx, i - lastIdx);
                lastIdx = i + 1;
            }
        }
        yield return str.Substring(lastIdx);
    }
```

Comment: And push both quotes and `[` s onto it? What about escape chars? Would you push those on too?

Comment: well, its more of a question to you. Do you support nested brackets? If you do, then push `ParserState.Bracketed` every time you encounter `'['`. If not, then push the first one and treat other ones as plain text. Same goes for combination of brackets and quotes.

Comment: as for the escape chars - yes I would push those. Basically you want the `state.Peek()` to be "this is where I am at NOW". SO if you encountered escape character then your following loop pass needs to know about it. Also I am a bit confused: You are not unescaping your escape chars on output? Is that an oversight or intended?

Comment: Mm... not sure... haven't actually needed to escape anything in practice yet. I don't know if this method should handle unescaping, or that should be delegated to the method that actually using this function. It's all internal anyway.

Comment: `Peeo, Pop, Push, Substring`. It's kinda catchy :)